# Error while trying to add polygon onto an image using opencv's fillPolly

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to add a triangle polygon on to an image using the following code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

// image here is a dummy image say 700*400 pixel one
triangle = np.array([(100, 20), (500, 20), (350, 180)], dtype=np.int32)
mask_image = np.zeros_like(image)
cv2.fillPoly(mask_image, triangle, 255)
```

I referred to some other answers where they say np.array will be creating the elements with dtype int64 so I explicitly changed to int32. Still no luck, I get the same error. Here is the error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-a13585bb05c1>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/home/niranjrajasekaran/Documents/personal/selfcar/lane_finder.py', wdir='/home/niranjrajasekaran/Documents/personal/selfcar')

  File "/home/niranjrajasekaran/.virtualenvs/selfcar/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/home/niranjrajasekaran/.virtualenvs/selfcar/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/home/niranjrajasekaran/Documents/personal/selfcar/lane_finder.py", line 37, in <module>
    roi = region_of_interest(canny_image)

  File "/home/niranjrajasekaran/Documents/personal/selfcar/lane_finder.py", line 30, in region_of_interest
    cv2.fillPoly(mask_image, triangle, 255)

error: OpenCV(4.1.1) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/drawing.cpp:2403: error: (-215:Assertion failed) p.checkVector(2, CV_32S) >= 0 in function 'fillPoly'
```

**Note: I am using OpenCV 4.1.1 and python 3.6.3**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my bad I haven't added `[]` to the numpy array which caused this error

```
triangle = np.array([ [(100, 20), (500, 20), (350, 180)] ], dtype=np.int32)
```

**Note: Even converting `dtype=np.int32` is not required**